# UglifyJS 2 browser build download

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, uglifyjs

Where can I download the browser build of [UglifyJS 2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)? I'm having trouble building it myself.

I installed `uglify-js` with npm. I just don't know where to run the `uglifyjs --self` command to build the browser version. I keep getting this error:

> 'uglifyjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Also in the browser build, I'm not sure how to minify a string of javascript code. I figured out that I can do `UglifyJS.parse(scriptEl.innerHTML)` to create an object tree of the parsed JS, then I can use the `.print_to_string();` method to convert it back to a string but without the whitespace, but I can't figure out what method to use to fully minify it including variable renaming and such.

Comment: Not entirely sure why you'd want to run this in the browser, but there's a minified concatenated version running in *their* browser demo: http://lisperator.net/s/js/uglifyjs/uglify.js~f67cb55ebe11ee800bda952cd6247363a3a43f7b ?

Comment: @meagar Do you know what method to use to minify JS using that build?

Comment: I'd like to eager @meagar, why would you want to minify browser-side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head over to http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/

> Once you installed it for NodeJS, UglifyJS2 provides a quick way to build itself for the browser:
>
> ```
> uglifyjs --self -c -m -o ./tmp/uglifyjs.js
> ```

The command worked for me. Now, you can use it in your browser straight away.

For specifying the options for the methods, you should look at:

- http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/codegen
- http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/compress
- http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/mangle

Note: the error you're getting when you run `uglifyjs` in your command-line seems like your terminal is not able to locate the installed file. Try to do a global install using `npm -g install uglify-js` or use the command from the directory where you installed it in.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the links to the compress and mangle pages. You'll get the bounty in ~23 hours.

Comment: This is probably obvious to experienced node.js users, but it was not for me: the line `uglifyjs --self -c -m -o ./tmp/uglifyjs.js` needs to be run from command line (Node.js command prompt), not from Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

I think you installed uglifyjs which is what I also installed the first time. Use:

```
npm install -g uglify-js
```

to install it. Note the extra hyphen. Also, note the "-g" option which is needed if you want to use it as a command-line application. Without the "-g" flag, you can still use it in node programs but not on the command line. After that running `uglifyjs --self` worked like a charm.

To answer the second part of your problem, do this:

```
var result = scripts.join("\n\n");  # concat
result = UglifyJS.minify(result, {fromString: true});
console.log(result.code);
```

Hope this helps.