# uglify.js, browser version returns "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, minify, client-side, uglifyjs

Using the uglify.js [browser-version](http://lisperator.net/s/js/uglifyjs/uglify.js), as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027492/uglifyjs-2-browser-build-download), on the first comment of the OP & getting this error in Chrome console: "UglifyJS.minify is not a function at FileReader."

The code used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://lisperator.net/s/js/uglifyjs/uglify.js"></script>
    <style>
        #drop_zone{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px dashed #bbb;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="drop_zone">
        <span>Drag and drop HTML files to minify</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        console.log(UglifyJS);
        var filesAr = [],
        dz = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function(file) {
                    return function(e) {
                        var minfd = UglifyJS.minify(e.target.result).code;
                        filesAr.push({name: file.name, min: minfd});
                    };
                })(f);
                reader.readAsText(f);
            }
            console.log(filesAr);
        }
        function handleDragOver(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        }
        dz.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
        dz.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whatever is wrong with this code?

Comment: what does console.log(UglifyJS) give you?

Comment: {AST_Token: ƒ, AST_Node: ƒ, AST_Statement: ƒ, AST_Debugger: ƒ, AST_Directive: ƒ, …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minify does not appear to be a function. See the instructions for the code you are using here: https://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/mangle.

Replace `UglifyJS.minify(e.target.result).code;` with the below and you should get the result you want.

```
let ast = UglifyJS.parse(code);

// compressor needs figure_out_scope too
ast.figure_out_scope();
let compressor = UglifyJS.Compressor()
ast = ast.transform(compressor);

// need to figure out scope again so mangler works optimally
ast.figure_out_scope();
ast.compute_char_frequency();
ast.mangle_names();

// get Ugly code back :)
let code = ast.print_to_string();
```

Comment: that gives me :code is not defined at FileReader.<anonymous>

Comment: try again now (I made an edit), here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-hill-cn99np?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://lisperator.net/s/js/uglifyjs/uglify.js"></script>
    <style>
        #drop_zone{
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 2px dashed #bbb;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="drop_zone">
        <span>Drag and drop HTML files to minify</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        var filesAr = [],
        dz = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
        const UglifyJS = window.UglifyJS;
        console.log(UglifyJS);
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
            for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (function(file) {
                    return function(e) {
                        let ast = UglifyJS.parse(e.target.result);
                        ast.figure_out_scope();
                        let compressor = UglifyJS.Compressor()
                        ast = ast.transform(compressor);
                        ast.figure_out_scope();
                        ast.compute_char_frequency();
                        ast.mangle_names();
                        let code = ast.print_to_string();
                        console.log(code);
                        filesAr.push({name: file.name, min: minfd});
                    };
                })(f);
                reader.readAsText(f);
            }
            console.log(filesAr);
        }
        function handleDragOver(evt) {
            evt.stopPropagation();
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
        }
        dz.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
        dz.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

here's what I have now: I had to put the uploaded file content, hence UglifyJS.parse(e.target.result);
But still no joy...
I get in console:
Uncaught $ {message: 'Unexpected token: operator (<)'
for each file.

Comment: This is a reply to Melbourne2991's suggestion below

Comment: @melbourne2291: To be fair, the question has been answered. The error I mention above concerns the parsing of the dropped files.

Comment: Just guessing here, does the code contain any jsx? that could be it?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It wasn't jsx but ES6. That version of uglify only supports ES5.